# ReferenceError: Shell MongoDB

Tags: javascript, sql, mongodb, nosql

Me sale un error que no se como resolver, cuando intento crear una base de datos con:

```
use peliculas
```

me sale un error que dice:

```
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: db id not defined
```

Comment: Hace falta más información para intentar encontrar el error. ¿qué versión de MongoDB utilizas? ¿Estos comandos los ejecutas desde el *shell* de MongoDB? En qué momento intentas usar `db`?

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que crear tu base de datos antes de poder usarla.

Para crear una base de datos usas la siguiente sentencia:

```
create database peliculas;
```

Para usarla ejecutas esta sentencia:

```
use peliculas;
```

Comment: En `mongodb`, desde el *shell*, no es necesario *crear* una base de datos de forma explícita, basta con usar la sentencia `use <database>` y Mongo responde con un mensaje: `switched to db <database>`. El error que muestra el OP es posiblemente debido a otro probelam.